# Issues with hello world wxWidgets project in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

While I was building the "hello world" project from the official wxWidget site in Code::Blocks, I got the following error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in wxTest2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN8wxObjectaSERKS_':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\object.h|394|undefined reference to `wxObject::Ref(wxObject const&)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN23wxCriticalSectionLockerC1ER17wxCriticalSection':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\thread.h|307|undefined reference to `wxCriticalSection::Enter()'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN23wxCriticalSectionLockerD1Ev':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\thread.h|312|undefined reference to `wxCriticalSection::Leave()'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN11wxTrackable10RemoveNodeEP13wxTrackerNode':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\tracker.h|57|undefined reference to `wxTheAssertHandler'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\tracker.h|57|undefined reference to `wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\tracker.h|57|undefined reference to `wxTrapInAssert'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\tracker.h|57|undefined reference to `wxTrapInAssert'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZNK12wxWindowBase18GetBestVirtualSizeEv':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\window.h|534|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::GetBestSize() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZNK12wxWindowBase12CanBeFocusedEv':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\window.h|757|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::IsEnabled() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN12wxWindowBase25ProcessWindowEventLocallyER7wxEvent':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\window.h|892|undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZNK12wxWindowBase10HasCaptureEv':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\window.h|1128|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::GetCapture()'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZNK12wxWindowBase20GetDefaultAttributesEv':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\window.h|1209|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::GetClassDefaultAttributes(wxWindowVariant)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZNK12wxWindowBase19DoGetBestClientSizeEv':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\window.h|1935|undefined reference to `wxDefaultSize'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\window.h|1935|undefined reference to `wxDefaultSize'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN8wxWindowC2Ev':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|35|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::wxWindowBase()'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|35|undefined reference to `vtable for wxWindow'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|35|undefined reference to `wxWindow::Init()'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|35|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase()'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN8wxWindow14ShowWithEffectE12wxShowEffectj':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|89|undefined reference to `wxWindow::MSWShowWithEffect(bool, wxShowEffect, unsigned int)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN8wxWindow14HideWithEffectE12wxShowEffectj':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|94|undefined reference to `wxWindow::MSWShowWithEffect(bool, wxShowEffect, unsigned int)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN8wxWindow20MSWEndDeferWindowPosEv':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|788|undefined reference to `wxDefaultPosition'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|788|undefined reference to `wxDefaultPosition'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|789|undefined reference to `wxDefaultSize'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\window.h|789|undefined reference to `wxDefaultSize'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN20wxTopLevelWindowBase8IsActiveEv':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\toplevel.h|214|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::FindFocus()'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\toplevel.h|214|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::IsDescendant(wxWindowBase*) const'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN7wxFrame19MSWTranslateMessageEP6tagMSG':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\frame.h|97|undefined reference to `wxFrame::MSWDoTranslateMessage(wxFrame*, tagMSG*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN17wxMDIClientWindowC1Ev':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\msw\mdi.h|257|undefined reference to `vtable for wxMDIClientWindow'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN20wxMDIParentFrameBase9TryBeforeER7wxEvent':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\mdi.h|401|undefined reference to `wxEVT_MENU'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\mdi.h|402|undefined reference to `wxEVT_UPDATE_UI'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\mdi.h|411|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::IsDescendant(wxWindowBase*) const'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include\wx\mdi.h|419|undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::TryBefore(wxEvent&)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x10)||undefined reference to `wxFrame::GetClassInfo() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x14)||undefined reference to `wxObject::CreateRefData() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x18)||undefined reference to `wxObject::CloneRefData(wxRefCounter const*) const'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x1c)||undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::SetNextHandler(wxEvtHandler*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x20)||undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::SetPreviousHandler(wxEvtHandler*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x24)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x28)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent(wxEvent*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x30)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::SearchEventTable(wxEventTable&, wxEvent&)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x38)||undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x40)||undefined reference to `wxFrame::GetEventTable() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x44)||undefined reference to `wxFrame::GetEventHashTable() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x48)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::DoSetClientObject(wxClientData*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x4c)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::DoGetClientObject() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x50)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::DoSetClientData(void*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x54)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::DoGetClientData() const'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x58)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::WXReservedEvtHandler1(void*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x5c)||undefined reference to `wxEvtHandler::WXReservedEvtHandler2(void*)'|
obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[__ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x60)||undefined reference to `wxTopLevelWindowMSW::Destroy()'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|
```

I am using Code:Blocks 20.3, Windows 10 x64, without the MinGW installation from Code::Blocks.
I independently installed MYSYS2 MinGW compiler with gcc 13.2.0.
And I am using wxWidgets 3.2.

I used CMake to build wxWidgets.
(I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVKYRPbKOX8&t=23s) tutorial to build it. Other tutorials that suggested to use `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc` didn't work for me, and my command prompt throws error like: `if not exist ".." mkdir "..". process. CreateProcess(null,..,..)failed.`)

My Build options in Code::Blocks read:

```
"project name">search directories>compiler>C:\Programe Files(x86)\wxWidgets\include

"project name">search directories>linker>C:\Programe Files(x86)\wxWidgets\gcc_x64_dll
(i don't have "gcc_dll" folder in wxWidgets directory, only "gcc_x64_dll" is present)

Debug>Search directories>Compiler>C:\Programe Files(x86)\wxWidgets\gcc_x64_dll\mswud

Debug>Linker settings>Link libraries: "wxmsw32ud_core","wxbasw32ud"
(same for release, but without "d")
```

A few things that I tried out and didn't work:

1. As some forums suggested that it's linker error and it had to do with linker settings. I tried various combination of libraries (of course remembering to change the version from 31 to 32 and keeping in mind to note the "ud" and "u" versions.).
   here are two of the combinations that I tried (for debugging):
   (libwxmsw32ud_core ; libwxbase32ud)
   (wxmsw32ud_core; wxbase32ud)
2. I also tried building the project with only `#include <wx/wx.h>`in the main.cpp. It threw same `undefined reference to` type of error but this time when clicking on the error it opened some header files.
3. I tried building the `hello world` program on a new project with nothing in the project build option to hopefully weed out something more. When I don't add the `include` directory to the compiler in search directories, it threw a single fatal error saying that it couldn't find the "wx.h" file.
   But when I add the `include` directory of wxwidgets, the fatal error now becomes `undefined reference to..` type of error.
4. Prior to all this, I tried to use prebuilt binary of wxWidgets. I got the same linker error on the pre built method. I also tried building it through command prompt with `mingw32 -make -f makefile.gcc......` command. But I could never build it this way because the it gave error while building saying something like: `(if not exist ".." mkdir "..". process: CreateProcess(Null, "...", ..). failed)`.

Please let me know if it's strictly just linking issue, or issue in building the library, or my Code::Blocks is setup wrong.
(I am new to building projects and libraries. please be a little understanding if this is a very silly issue.)

Comment: Learn how to build this from the command line first, then figure out how to make CB run the same command. *"Independently installed mysys32 mingw compiler"* You mean MSYS2?

Comment: Here's what I'd try: 1. Install wxWidgets using MSYS2's `pacman` (I'm sure that their version works, but I'm not sure about the one you've built). 2. Run `wx-config --libs --cflags` to get the correct compiler flags. 3. Build from MSYS2 terminal with `g++ blah.cpp`, followed by the flags you got from `wx-config`. If this doesn't work, come back with the full log from the MSYS2 terminal.

Comment: @Adua, it is recommended to not to mix 2 different build systems `CMake` and `MinGW` in your case. Especially if you are using IDE. Please use `CMake` for everything or use `MinGW` build of wxWidgets.

Comment: @Adua, as Xaviou said - its very easy to build the library with `MinGW`. And since C::B does not support `CMake` I suggest you do that and use standard default way of building the library and use it  with your choice of IDE.

Comment: hello @HolyBlackCat . yes, I meant MYSYS2. I am trying to build the library again by the method you suggested. I installed wx through pacman and when I wrote the command `wx-config --libs --cflags` it gave out bunch of texts not in a same line. The output reads: `-IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-3.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMSW__ -fpermissive
-LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib   -pipe -Wl,--subsys...........`. Not I am not sure how to build with this. shall I write: `mingw32-make -f makefile.cpp cflags` or something different

Comment: @Igor I see, thanking you for mentioning. I'll keep that in mind next time. I don't know much about Cmake or even Mingw. I am just familiar the command: `gcc filename.cpp -o filename` since i haven't build/compile anything that requires beyond one cpp file

Comment: As I already said, you write `g++ your_file.cpp ...`, where ... is this output you got (remove line breaks from it).

Comment: hello @HolyBlackCat . I was able to finally build it through command prompt. I think having multiple compiler and having all of them set up in path environment variable had caused the CreateProcess(NULL,..,..)failed issue (suggested by this guide[link](https://github.com/PBfordev/wxpbguide)). Now I am afraid  if i try building wxWidgets with mysys2; it would break previous stuff. I hope you understand. But nevertheless thank you for taking out your time to help me. I might even try re-building wx with mysy2 next time after I am content with exploring wx

Comment: Whatever works for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of `Makefile.gcc`, there should be some code like `cmd=$(ComSpec)`. To avoid the `CreateProcess` failure, change it to `cmd=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. That is, replace `$(ComSpec)` with the value in the `ComSpec` environment variable. This change should be made to every makefile that MinGW32-make executes.

Comment: thank you very much. It dose seem to solve the CreateProcess issue when building from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

It really seems to be a linker problem.
Could you post the full command line used by Code::Blocks (to activate this, do to "Settings", "Compiler", select your compiler, go to the "Other settings" sub tab, and select "Full command line" as compiler logging option).

For you man build with mingw-make problem, you first have to run the command line with the "setup_h" build target :

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc setup_h other_options_of_your_command_line
```

And when its done, you can launch the samea command line without the "setup_h" build target.

And if you don't want to loose your time with building the libs yourself (I know it takes a long time), you'll find my pre-build binaries [here.](https://wxstuff.xaviou.fr/)

Comment: I've edited this to add that those are your binaries ([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)), and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/353058

Comment: I have the same settings as you mention. I am guessing build log besides the build message refers to the command line. here's what it reads: g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_x64_dll" -LC:\MinGW\bin -o bin\Debug\wxTest.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lwxbase32ud -lwxmsw32ud_core
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `WinMain@16':
E:/Dawg/wxTest/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `wxEntry(HINSTANCE__*, 
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))
50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) (I LEFT OUT THE LINKER ERRORS IN BETWEEN TO MEET THE CHARACTER LIMIT)

Comment: when I tried the command `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc setup_h SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug` it gave the same error: `if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, -c "if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll", ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile.gcc:5972: recipe for target '..\..\lib\gcc_dll' failed
mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll] Error 2`

Comment: "clean" command doesn't help either. it gives the same error with: `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug clean`

Comment: sir I also tried downloading a binary from the site you mentioned (wxwidget 3.2.3, with header file only. gcc 13.2.0 -64 bits static monolithic). It gave me the same undefined reference to error. I used "wxmsw32ud" in the linker setting. got the same error when I added "wxmsw32ud_gl" and "wxzlibd" in desperation inside the linker setting. It's feels like no matter what I add in the linker setting, the linker just ignores everything.

Comment: I also tried static-multilib build from site. Same error.

Comment: @Adua, did you see this: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47233&sid=7743cdfcc68698cc636adfbf7beecea5 and https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47231?

Comment: @Igor I haven't checked them yet. Will do after I finish attempting to build it through MYSYS2 terminal suggested but a comment on the question. Thanks for the link to additional resources though. I only have check docs in official website and a few dozen of video on yt that do the same thing; just steps, no explanation.

Comment: @Adua, please cancel the build - you will not go anywhere with it. check those links and follow them up, especially the second one.

Comment: I recommend using shared binaries instead of static ones : in this last case, there is a lot of libraries and when using MinGW, the linking order has its importance. You can have a look at the following link ( https://github.com/XPsoud/wxSnippets/blob/master/TestApp/TestApp.cbp ) : it refers to a Code::Blocks project file with multiple configurations so you will be able to compare with yours.

Comment: @Igor  Words can't explain how grateful I am to you for sharing that second guide. Sorry for responding late. I almost forgot about stack overflow once the pdf guide worked and I just started messing around with wx the whole day. Thank you Sir/Ma'am.

Comment: @Xaviou linking order? interesting, I never thought of that. I might try out different orders. And for the cbp file.... I am not sure if I would be capable to deducing anything meaningful after comparing the cbp file. But will do when I get further more into code blocks. But for now, I am using a guide that is working for my system and I am able to build the library and make sample files too. Thank you taking out time to reply though. I truly appreciate it.